# Setting record CurrencyIsoCode from Flow using Custom Setting picklist

Tags: picklist, visual-workflow, customsetting, flow

I'm trying to implement Cloud4Good's [guide](http://cloud4good.com/announcements/flexibility-in-flows-custom-settings-and-dynamic-picklists/) to setting picklist values in Flows, based on a Custom Setting list.

I've created the CS list, naming each record to match the standard picklist values `GBP - British Pound`, `EUR - Euro` & `USD - U.S. Dollar`.

Then I've configured the dynamic choice field as follows

[image]

Set the field as the choice for my screen's Currency field picklists

[image]

And mapped the field to the new record's standard `CurrencyIsoCode` field.

[image]

When I test the Flow, the picklist field displays 3 values but they're all `GBP` (my default currency) and also the currency that's set for the record when it's created.

I've also tried naming my fields `GBP`, `EUR` and `USD` and even `British Pound`, `Euro` and `U.S. Dollar` which has no effect.

What do I need to change in order to set these values ([assuming that they can be set in a Flow](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001rzc&fId=0D53000001YPxR1))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex - as we discussed on our extremely long twitter exchange:

Two things:

1) Its always good to switch that "Currency1" dynamic choice to a variable for the Record Creation.  So use an Assignment element to do that after your Screen.  I'll note, this is NOT required.  I just find it best to reference a variable rather than a Screen Input as I work in my Flow.

2) You need to replace the "CurrencyIsoCode" in your Label on the Dynamic Choice to be "Name".  Currently you're only brining in your GBP value instead of the ones for each value you have.

That should do the trick :)!

I've attached a quick example of #1, just for reference:
[image]